# Detach thread right after creation and memory leaks

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-leaks, pthreads

I'm trying to create a detached thread so I won't need to free the memory allocated for it.
Valgrind is used to check for memory leaks.
I've used [IBM example](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/apis/users_60.htm) and written:

```
void *threadfunc(void *parm)
{
  printf("Inside secondary thread\n");
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  pthread_t             thread;
  int                   rc=0;
  rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadfunc, NULL);
  sleep(1);
  rc = pthread_detach(thread);
  return 0;
}
```

this works and doesn't create leaks, but a version without "sleep(1);" doesn't.
Why is this sleep(1) needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a detached thread so I won't need to free the
>   memory allocated for it.

In this case, *pthread_detach*() is not be required and hence should not be used. Additionaly, in this code snippet you have not done any explict memory allocation, so you should not worry about the freeing the memory.

> Why is this sleep(1) needed?

When you create the new thread, parent and child threads can starts executing in any order.
Its depends on the OS schedular and other factors. Now in this case if parent threads gets
scheduled first then it is possible that its goes and exit the program before child thread
starts execution.

By adding sleep in the parent context, the child thread is getting time to start and finish the execution before finished. But this is not  good idea and as we do not know how much time child thread will take. hence *pthread_jon()* should be used in the parent context. For detailed information please refer to POSIX thread documentation and great arcicle from below link

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: 'First of all, pthread_detach() is dangerours and should not be used(almost).' - why?

Comment: @MartinJames: Simple reason would be it is difficult to find out trace about detached thread.While reading the TC++PL, 4th edition, Bjrane Stroustrup has mentioned about it why it is not so good practice to use thread::detach. Here my intention was that in this case it is not required for the situation which user has mentioned. I have modified my statements about this.